# Рандомное скрытие части картинки в карточке с помощью грид и/или react

Tags: css, reactjs, opacity

У меня есть картинка в карточке. Я хочу, чтобы по умолчанию для обычных пользователей отображалась лишь часть ее (например, рандомный квадрат с шириной, равной 10% от размера картинки). Я делаю это через добавление поверх картинки div c background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);. Если сделать этому квадрату фиксированное положение, я понимаю, что это можно реализовать с помощью 4-х div, спозиционированных таким образом, чтобы в каком-то месте между этими divами оставалась брешь и была видна часть картинки. Первый вопрос, можно ли реализовать подобное, используя 1 div через гриды, то есть убирая background конкретной ячейке? Второй, как реализовать, чтобы этот квадрат был рандомно расположен на картинке с помощью react c помощью тех же гридов, или как то передавать данные вычислений случайных координат в свойства тех самых 4 divов?

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере в качестве маски используется свойство `box-shadow` у абсолютно позиционированного псевдоэлемента, размещенного поверх картинки.

По клику положение псевдоэлемента меняется случайным образом, принимая значения кратные его ширине (10%).

```js
const picture =  document.getElementById('picture');
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
function cutPicture() {
  let shiftTop = getRandomInt(0,9) * 10 + '%';
  let shiftLeft = getRandomInt(0,9) * 10 + '%';
  picture.style.setProperty('--top', shiftTop);
  picture.style.setProperty('--left', shiftLeft);
}
picture.addEventListener('click', e => { cutPicture() });
cutPicture();
```

```css
#picture {
  background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2giQVPIl9JM/maxresdefault.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  --top: 0;
  --left: 0;
} 
#picture::after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width:10%;
  height:10%;
  top: var(--top);
  left: var(--left);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 100vh rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
}
```

```html
<div id="picture"></div>
```